# ggplot2: Is it possible to reuse values in the same layer?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I would like to plot all values under a certain range in a column, but dynamically determine which range based on a column value.

To illustrate, here's a toy data frame:

```
x y  pval
1 3 0.100
2 4 0.050
3 5 0.010
4 6 0.005
```

I want to generate a plot that, for a specific variable (`pval`), I want to display all rows with that `pval` or lower. Here's what the plot would look like:
[image]

Maybe something like: `ggplot(df, aes(x=df[which(df$pval < pval)]$x, y=df[which(df$pval < pval)]$y)) + facet_wrap(~ pval)`. Again, is this possible within ggplot2 without constructing a new data frame? I have massive datasets that would take a couple of days to regenerate.

Comment: `ggplot` doesn't do much to transform or subset your data. It's really just for plotting, so tasks like this aren't really possible with faceting without repeating rows in the data set. It may be easier to draw 4 separate plots and then use `arrageGrob` to put them together. Exactly how large is your data? If you are unlikely to be able to see all the points, you may consider reducing your data by rounding to a certain number of decimals and then removing duplicate rows. This can greatly speed up plotting.

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you make a reproducible example to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to solve your problem. You can have a look at [this SO post on how to make a great reproducible example in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MrFlick I found a similar functionality in `stat_ecdf()`, and based on [the source code](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-ecdf.r), it seems to create a new data frame based on `ecdf()`. In that vein, it seems reasonable to construct a new data frame containing different subsets, with the caveat that `stat_ecdf()` reduces the amount of data for plotting and this increases it.